# Error coercing raster to SpatialPixelsDataFrame in R

Tags: raster, r, sp, vectorization, climate

I obtain the below error when I try to coerce my raster to a vector.

Initially my rasters are of different extents and I use the projectRaster tool to obtain the same extent for both the rasters. However, when I coerce the two to a Spatial Pixels Data Frame in R, I get different number of elements. Why is this happening?

```
> bio5
 class       : RasterLayer 
 dimensions  : 339, 246, 83394  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
 resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
 extent      : 72.45835, 82.70835, 8.083337, 22.20834  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
 data source : in memory
 names       : bio_5 
 values      : 20.7, 43.2  (min, max)
```

Before Projection:

```
> lg5
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 339, 246, 83394  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent      : 72.45833, 82.70833, 8.083333, 22.20833  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : cclgmbi5 
values      : 18.7, 39.2  (min, max)
```

After Projection:

```
new.lg5 <- projectRaster(lg5,bio5)
> new.lg5
 class       : RasterLayer 
 dimensions  : 339, 246, 83394  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
 resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
 extent      : 72.45835, 82.70835, 8.083337, 22.20834  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
 data source : in memory
 names       : cclgmbi5 
 values      : 18.70035, 39.2  (min, max)
```

Coercing them to a vector:

```
 > x <- as(bio5,"SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
 > y <- as(new.lg5, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
 > str(x)
  Formal class 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 7 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 54202 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ bio_5: num [1:54202] 40.3 40.3 40.3 40.4 40.4 40.3 40.2 40.2 40.3 40.3 ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : num(0) 
  ..@ grid       :Formal class 'GridTopology' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
  .. .. ..@ cellcentre.offset: Named num [1:2] 72.5 8.1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "s1" "s2"
  .. .. ..@ cellsize         : num [1:2] 0.0417 0.0417
  .. .. ..@ cells.dim        : int [1:2] 246 339
  ..@ grid.index : int [1:54202] 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ...
  ..@ coords     : num [1:54202, 1:2] 72.6 72.6 72.7 72.8 72.8 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 72.5 8.08 82.71 22.21
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

  > str(y)
   Formal class 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 7 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 54747 obs. of  1 variable:
   .. ..$ cclgmbi5: num [1:54747] 37.6 37.4 37.4 37.4 37.4 ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : num(0) 
  ..@ grid       :Formal class 'GridTopology' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
   .. .. ..@ cellcentre.offset: Named num [1:2] 72.5 8.1
   .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "s1" "s2"
  .. .. ..@ cellsize         : num [1:2] 0.0417 0.0417
  .. .. ..@ cells.dim        : int [1:2] 246 339
  ..@ grid.index : int [1:54747] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...
  ..@ coords     : num [1:54747, 1:2] 72.6 72.6 72.6 72.7 72.7 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 72.46 8.08 82.71 22.21
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Comment: @Vijay_Ramesh, please provide the clipped data, that would be helpful for an answer.

Comment: I'm aware this is not providing an answer and it can gladly be turned into a comment. Yet I might know an answer if I could play around with the data a little. Sorry for the inconvinience, I'm working on the reputation.

Comment: No problem at all. I completely understand :). As I mentioned in the comment to Edzer below and I have linked the data as well. All I did was download the data and clipped it. BUT, I also realized that the two datasets before clipping differ in their extent at ymin by the 6th decimal place bio - 90.00001, and lgm - 90. So, I resampled and ensured that the extents are the same, following which I clipped it. But, I realized as Edzer mentioned that when your coerce to a SpatialPixels Dataframe, it keeps only those rows that have NO missing values. Feel free to take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't give the data, I can only guess, but my guess is that your raster contains missing values; SpatialPixelDataFrame objects ignore raster cells with missing values for all attributes/layers.

Comment: The data am using is the raw data downloaded from the WorldClim website for Current Climate and Last Glacial Maximum (at resolution of 2.5arc min). I downloaded bio5 for both time frames to start with and I clipped it with a mask for my region. You might be right that, they could have missing values. Any suggestions?   (Can provide clipped data if you want to take a look?) http://www.worldclim.org/version1

Comment: I took a look at the raster and yup, it's replacing all rows with missing data.  Thanks for the answer!